# xlsxwiter: text_wrap() not showing start of string

Tags: python, xlrd, xlsxwriter

```
               if WritteTorow%2 == 0 :
                    each_row_format=workbook.add_format({
                               'bg_color':"#dddddd",
                               'border':0,
                               'text_wrap' : True
                            })
               else:
                    each_row_format=workbook.add_format({'text_wrap' : True})
```

Here is example 
Ex : text_wrap() is showing end string in cell, In cell its not showing stating string , O/p in cell :  not showing stating string , Im expecting : text_wrap() is showing end string in cell

Comment: There isn’t enough information there to figure out what is going on. Please add a small complete working example that demonstrates the issue.